# Create XML via PHP & MySQL (for use by action script 2)

Tags: php, mysql, xml, actionscript-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php)
>   [Get MySQL database output via PHP to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112282/get-mysql-database-output-via-php-to-xml)

I have some tables in MySQL.... Can I use PHP to create a .xml file on my website that will neatly contain the information from my MySQL database?

On a side note if I am retrieving xml information in action script 2.0 do I HAVE to retrieve it from a .xml file or can I have a .php file that creates an  open and close tag on the page and then creates an xml table on the .php page?

Comment: Asked as a separate question because of the ActionScript 2 part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create XML in PHP and you can save it as file or echo as XML string , you can use below sample codes

```
        $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');

        $rootNode = $xml->createElement('xmlrootnode');
        $rootNode = $xml->appendChild($rootNode);

        foreach( $resultArr as $r )  {

            $sDateArr = explode( ' ', $r['start_time'] );
            $sRootN = $xml->createElement('date');
            $sRootN = $rootNode->appendChild($sRootN);
            $sRootN->setAttribute('value', $sDateArr[0]);

            //Id field
            $idN = $xml->createElement('id');
            $idN = $sRootN->appendChild($idN);

            $idT = $xml->createTextNode(htmlentities($r['id']));
            $idN->appendChild($idT);
        }
        //$xml->save($xml);
        //header('Content-type: text/xml');
        //echo $xmlStr = $xml->saveXML();
        $xmlStr = isset($xml) ? htmlspecialchars($xml->saveXML()) : '';
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the productive response!

Answer (score 1):

As an answer to your side note:
Yes you can - thats the normal way to do it.
AS does not even know if it was a file or created on the fly - it just receives the data and if it is valid XML it should work...