# Export sql to xml with utf8 encoding

Tags: sql, xml, encoding

I try to find a solution by extracting sql table values in utf8 encoding but no luck.
The bellow code exports a right XML file named "test.xml" but without encoding. 
Any suggestions?

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "admin";
$dbname = "My_DB";
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$sql = "SELECT product_id, model, image  FROM product";
$q = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error()); 


$xml = "<products>";
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){

  $xml .= "<product>";

 $xml .= "<id>";  
 $xml .= "<![CDATA[".$r["product_id"]."]]>";
 $xml .= "</id>";
 $xml .= "<name><![CDATA[" . $r["model"] . "]]></name>";
 $xml .= "<image>".$r['image']."</image>";   
 $xml .= "</product>";  
}

$xml .= "</products>";
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->asXML("test.xml");

?>
```

Comment: Don't know which DB you are using, but `mysql` have the `--xml` switch to output in XML. You should consider taking a look to this SO thead too http://stackoverflow.com/a/5112417/465183

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is adding all data in a variable and then just outputting it to a file. Why don't you try formatting your XML file as you want it (instead of using `SimpleXMLElement` only in the end? What I mean is something like this:

```
[...]
$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$xml .= "<products>";
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){

  $xml .= "<product>";

 $xml .= "<id>";  
 $xml .= "<![CDATA[".$r["product_id"]."]]>";
 $xml .= "</id>";
 $xml .= "<name><![CDATA[" . $r["model"] . "]]></name>";
 $xml .= "<image>".$r['image']."</image>";   
 $xml .= "</product>";  
}

$xml .= "</products>";

echo $xml;
```

This will result to an XML file created on your own. Just saying because you are not using the `SimpleXMLElement` all the way, instead you are adding the XML elements and attributes manually. You can take a look at [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) to see how else you could have built your file!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis i' ll try it and info you.

Comment: Just make sure to save the `$xml` var to a file, for example with `file_put_contents("myXMLfile.xml, $xml);`

Comment: It works fine. And it is a perfect way without add an extra load for memory.